# section/item numbering right to left

Tags: polyglossia

Since upgrading MiKTeX I have a problem with bilingual documents English/Arabic: All header numberings, the numbers of an enumerated list (in English) and any number in regular English text which is immediately followed by a period is typeset right to left.

Here is an example:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[11pt, DIV=15, BCOR=10mm,parskip=half, headings=normal,openright,headsepline, 
chapterprefix=off]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Mapping=arabicdigits, Scale=1.6]{Scheherazade}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newcommand\rl{\textarabic}

\begin{document}
    \chapter[Chapter One]{XXXXX} 
        \section{YYYYY} 
            Enumerated lists, first in Arabic

    \begin{Arabic}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item   الكتاب جديد.    
            \item   الطالب جميل.  
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{Arabic}

    everything is OK. But in English .....

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item  An item in an English environment
        \item  Just a second one
    \end{enumerate}

\section{ZZZZZ} 
Now normal text in English. But when a number is followed by a period, we run into the same problem, like
"This happened in 1999."

If I change this to "This happened in 1999 .", just adding a space before the period, it works OK, only I don't want that space there.

\section{Exercises}
    \begin{Arabic}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item  الطالب في مكتب.
        \item  المدير في المكتب.
        \item  المكتبة بعيدة عن الجامعة.
        \item  المكتبة قريبة من الجامعة.
        \item  انا طالبة في هذه الجامعة.
        \item  انا المدير في هذا المكتب.
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \end{Arabic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a small LaTeX document showing the problem you encounter, such that it becomes possible to copy the code and run it on our installations. Use the `edit` button at the bottom of your post to add the code.

Comment: I actually supplied a small document which produces these errors, but I can't see it anymore. I must have done it wrong. Additionally I am temporarily banned from any more edits - no idea why. So I would happily supply it again with a little guidance.

Comment: I have no control over this platform. But if you give me the link to your document as a comment, I can add it to the question for you.

Comment: I have put the sample into my dropbox. The link to it is: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r7y4tyipbzsbexx/AACwegHvBBPHfS-2Zh54SYDQa?dl=0

Comment: This must be a problem specific to MiKTeX, or to this particular version of MiKTeX. I just compiled your document on Linux with TeXLive 2016, and it looks fine.

Comment: This is correct. I have MikTex 2.9 installed on one PC which was updated sometime early this year and it works fine. I have updated the other one only this week and this one shows the problem with the right/left numbering, The left/right arrangement when I use two columns in an Arabic environment, i.e. the text starts in the left instead of the right column, happens with both my MikTex installations.